# Repeat multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

How to implement multiple column repetition using formulas? Here is my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMXqlEPtPs2eBja42uj409fScvBggjrt23us1jUd3jk/edit#gid=0). For example, I need to repeat the range A1:C5 N-times so that the result is like in the range E1:G25. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your actual data will 3 columns only?

Comment: Yes, there will be 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to simplify below formula but it works-

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN("#";FALSE;"#"&A1:A5&"@"&B1:B5&"@"&C1:C5));5);"#"));"@";;FALSE))
```

See your sheet

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
={OFFSET(A1:C;;;COUNTA(A1:A));
  OFFSET(A1:C;;;COUNTA(A1:A));
  OFFSET(A1:C;;;COUNTA(A1:A));
  OFFSET(A1:C;;;COUNTA(A1:A));
  OFFSET(A1:C;;;COUNTA(A1:A))}
```

Comment: it worked, but not convenient if you need to do a large number of repetitions

Answer (score 0):

Another way, number of reps in D1, number of rows and columns in range to be copied can vary:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(
mod(quotient(sequence(D1*rows(A1:C5),columns(A1:C5),0),columns(A1:C5)),rows(A1:C5))+1,
{row(A1:C5),A1:C5},
mod(sequence(D1*rows(A1:C5),columns(A1:C5),0),columns(A1:C5))+2))
```

[image]

For your locale:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(
mod(quotient(sequence(P1*rows(A1:C5);columns(A1:C5);0);columns(A1:C5));rows(A1:C5))+1;
{row(A1:C5)\A1:C5};
mod(sequence(P1*rows(A1:C5);columns(A1:C5);0);columns(A1:C5))+2))
```